# Giving opt arguments to clang

Tags: optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to give opt arguments to clang?

For example:
`opt -loop-data-prefetch  file.ll` will enable an optimization step.

How can I use this argument when running `clang file.c` ?